# Swift compiler segfaults passing UnsafeMutablePointer to C function

Tags: swift

(XCode 7.2.1)

I have a Swift object that wants to pass itself to a C function :

```
some_c_function(UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()));
```

Where some_c_function is a C function accessed via a bridging header:

```
void some_c_function(void* swiftObject);
```

That call to some_c_function crashes the Swift compiler:

```
0  swift                    0x00000001028c2fbb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
1  swift                    0x00000001028c36fb SignalHandler(int) + 379
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff88809f1a _sigtramp + 26
3  swift                    0x00000001026a64cf llvm::DICompositeType::getImpl(llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int, llvm::MDString*, llvm::Metadata*, unsigned int, llvm::Metadata*, llvm::Metadata*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned int, llvm::Metadata*, unsigned int, llvm::Metadata*, llvm::Metadata*, llvm::MDString*, llvm::Metadata::StorageType, bool) + 975
4  swift                    0x0000000100ace9ad swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 10973
5  swift                    0x0000000100a35053 swift::irgen::IRGenModuleDispatcher::emitLazyDefinitions() + 307
6  swift                    0x0000000100ab549a performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 1034
7  swift                    0x0000000100ab5830 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 64
8  swift                    0x00000001009b4265 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 13701
9  swift                    0x00000001009b0ad3 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2691
10 swift                    0x00000001009ad154 main + 2324
11 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff8f1555c9 start + 1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possibly the type inference to the C function fails w.r.t. the passed pointer being a `void` pointer. Try splitting the pointer assignment (with explicit pointer type specification) and the c function call into two separate lines, e.g., `let ptr : UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())` followed by `some_c_function(ptr)`.

Comment: Your code looks correct and works for me, so there must be something else which triggers the compiler crash. You should try to reduce the problem to a *minimal* example. In any case, a crashing compiler is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: dfri: tried that, it's the C call that causes the compiler crash rather than than getting the pointer.